# Using Regular Expressions extract Method and Property

Tags: c#, regex

I using the following code to extract method and property from the string

```
string pattern = @"@[\w\.\()]+";
string value = "Create Account for @DisplayName() (Code : @Code)";
var reg = new Regex(pattern);
var matchs = reg.Matches(value);
foreach (var match in matchs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
```

The following is the result

```
@DisplayName()
@Code)
```

It is not my expected result, I expected result is the following

```
@DisplayName()
@Code
```

How can I do?

Comment: Regex on what language?

Comment: I using .Net framework 4

Answer (score 1):

You're allowing `)` in your class. Force `)` to be preceded by `(` and make the two together optional.

```
@[\w\.]+(\(\))?
```

Comment: You don't have to escape `.` inside a class.

Comment: Yeah good spot - I just copied that from the OP's part and corrected the necessary bit.

Comment: It does not work when string is "Create Account for @DisplayName().ToString() (Code : @Code)"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the regex pattern will need to support multiple properties and functions.

```
@"@\w+(\(\))?(\.\w+(\(\))?)*"
```